# CKEDITOR toolbar buttons do not show up

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

This...

```
CKEDITOR.replace('layout_edit', {
    toolbar: [
        [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ],
        [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'RemoveFormat', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight' ],
        [ 'FontSize' ]
    ]
})
```

...turns into this...

[image]

I don't know why the justify options and font size options don't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include a version of CKEDITOR that has the plugins you need. This does not have 'justify' or 'font':

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Try this:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```